# MotorBee dll and c++, memory access violation

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to control MotorBee using c++,
The problem is that I am using a dll file that came with MotorBee "mtb.dll"

I am trying to load the functions from the dll into my C++ program as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mt.h"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

HINSTANCE BeeHandle= LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR) "mtb.dll"); 
Type_InitMotoBee InitMotoBee;
Type_SetMotors SetMotors;
Type_Digital_IO Digital_IO;

int main() {
InitMotoBee = (Type_InitMotoBee)GetProcAddress( BeeHandle, " InitMotoBee");
SetMotors =(Type_SetMotors)GetProcAddress(BeeHandle, " SetMotors");
Digital_IO =(Type_Digital_IO)GetProcAddress(BeeHandle, " Digital_IO ");     InitMotoBee();
SetMotors(0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error saying that I am trying to read address 0x00000000 in memory,
when I try to cout BeeHandle it shows 0x0 address (trying to check the handle value)
sample error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in 111111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x6148f2b4 in 111111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x6148f2b4 in 111111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x6148f2b4 in 111111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x6148f2b4 in 111111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

thank you for the help,

Comment: Do the `GetProcAddress()` calls succeed? I doubt it, given the leading space in each of the string literals used for the function names.

Comment: If `BeeHandle` is `0` that means the DLL was not loaded successfully. Is it in the same folder as your application?

Comment: @hmjd exactly.. "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" indicates SetMotors is 0. Error handling is a Good Thing.

Comment: cout <<"check address: "<<GetProcAddress( BeeHandle, " InitMotoBee")<<endl; it will show 0x0000000

Comment: replacing (LPCWSTR) by L gives an error saying: L undeclared identifier

Comment: checking BeeHandle gives 0 which it seems to indecate that the dll was not loaded properly

Comment: how can I use GetLastError()? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cast is incorrect:

```
HINSTANCE BeeHandle= LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR) "mtb.dll");
```

as it casting an string literal to a wide string literal. Just use a wide string literal:

```
HINSTANCE BeeHandle = LoadLibrary(L"mtb.dll");
```

- Check result of `LoadLibrary()`:
- Check result of `GetProcAddress()` before attempting to use the returned function pointers. There is a leading space in each of the string literals (and a trailing space one as well, thanks to Roger in comments) used to specify the function names, remove them.
- If either `LoadLibrary()` or `GetProcAddress()` fails use [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the reason for failure.

Code summary:

```
HINSTANCE BeeHandle = LoadLibrary(L"mtb.dll");
if (BeeHandle)
{
    SetMotors = (Type_SetMotors)GetProcAddress(BeeHandle, "SetMotors");
    if (SetMotors)
    {
        // Use 'SetMotors'.
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to locate SetMotors(): " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    FreeLibrary(BeeHandle);
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to load mtb.dll: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Not actually illegal, just very inadvisable.

Comment: @John, I'll change the wording.

Comment: While you're editing, there's a trailing space on one of the functions too.

Comment: replacing (LPCWSTR) by L gives an error saying: L undeclared identifier

Comment: std::cerr << "Failed to locate SetMotors(): " << GetLastError() << "\n";
 gives the number 127

Comment: @saleh, use `net helpmsg <number>` in a command prompt to obtain a text description of the number. For example, `net helpmsg 127` outputs _The specified procedure could not be found._ To obtain the text programmatically use `FormatMessage()`.